# Computed value not updating in view unless list refreshes? (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swiftui

I come from a C# background and I am new to SwiftUI. I am trying to create an app that will help me track my grocery shopping. I want to display a list with a title and a bunch of products that I will later acquire at the store.

I gathered the products as an array inside a GroceryList class. I am able to add a new product, remove a product, move products in the list.

My issue comes when I display the amount of products that were acquired in the grocery list using a function in the GroceryList class: ProductAcquiredAmount(). That computed value only gets updated when I add, remove or move a product in the list. I want that computed value at the top to be updated every time I check a product as acquired.

[image]

The Product class:

```
class Product: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var acquired: Bool
    
    init(name: String, acquired: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.acquired = acquired
    }
}
```

The GroceryList class:

```
class GroceryList: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    @Published var date: String
    @Published var products: [Product]
    
    init(date: String, products: [Product]) {
        self.date = date
        self.products = products
    }
    
    func ProductAcquiredAmount() -> Int {
        var productAcquiredAmount = 0
        for product in self.products {
            if product.acquired {
                productAcquiredAmount = productAcquiredAmount + 1
            }
        }
        return productAcquiredAmount
    }
}
```

and the view:

```
struct GroceryMainView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var grocList: GroceryList = GroceryList(date: "Current list", products: [Product(name: "Potato", acquired: false), Product(name: "Bread", acquired: true), Product(name: "Coffee", acquired: false)])
    
    @State private var hideAcquiredProducts = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(content: {
                    ForEach($grocList.products) { $product in
                        if hideAcquiredProducts == false || (hideAcquiredProducts && product.acquired == false) {
                            ProductRow(product: product)
                        }
                    }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                        grocList.products.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                    }).onMove(perform: { indices, newOffset in
                        grocList.products.move(fromOffsets: indices, toOffset: newOffset)
                    })
                    NewProductRow(groceryList: grocList)
                }, header: {
                    HStack {
                        Text(grocList.date)
                            .font(.title3)
                            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                        Spacer()
                        Text("\(grocList.ProductAcquiredAmount()) / \(grocList.products.count)")
                            .font(.title3)
                            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    }
                })
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Grocery Lists")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    Toggle(isOn: $hideAcquiredProducts, label: {
                        Text("Focus Mode")
                    }).toggleStyle(.switch)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ProductRow: View {
    @ObservedObject var product: Product
    @State var productName: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                if self.product.acquired {
                    self.product.acquired = false
                } else {
                    self.product.acquired = true
                }
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: product.acquired ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
            })
            if product.acquired {
                TextField("", text: $product.name)
                    .strikethrough()
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            } else {
                TextField("", text: $product.name)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NewProductRow: View {
    @ObservedObject var groceryList: GroceryList
    @State var newProductName = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                let newProduct = Product(name: newProductName, acquired: false)
                newProductName = ""
                self.groceryList.products.append(newProduct)
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            })
            TextField("...", text: $newProductName)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you **do not** nest `ObservableObject` classes, like you have `Product` inside `GroceryList`. Make `Product` a `struct` (without the @Published) and use `@StateObject var grocList: GroceryList ...` in `GroceryMainView`. Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app 
[Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)

Comment: Model data is perfectly fine to have as an ObservableObject but ObservableObjects have to be wrapped with @ObservedObject at every level for you to see changes. See working dogs link above for an example you are simply mimicking “Book”

Comment: Something to note too is that Binding is for value types not reference

Comment: Thank you for your help and the link. I updated my GroceryList to a StateObject, removed the ObservableObject method for Product and made it a struct. I also updated my ProductRow view to take "Binding productName" and "Binding productAcquired" instead of the full product.

Answer (score -2):

Product should be a struct and `@ObservedObject` should be `@EnvironmentObject` and use `.environmentObject(GroceryList.shared)` in the App struct.